# Prediction failed: Error when checking input: expected dense_input to have shape (2898,) but got array with shape (1,)

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, google-cloud-platform, google-ai-platform

I am using the following script predictor.py in order to get predictions from a Keras model hosted in GCP AI Platform.

```
import os
import pickle
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import logging

class MyPredictor(object):

    def __init__(self, model, bow_model):
        self._model = model
        self._bow_model = bow_model

    def predict(self, instances, **kwargs):
      
        vectors = self.embedding([instances])

        vectors = vectors.tolist()

        output = self._model.predict(vectors)

        return output

    def embedding(self, statement):
        vector = self._bow_model.transform(statement).toarray()
        #vector = vector.to_list()
        return vector


    @classmethod
    def from_path(cls, model_dir):

        model_path = os.path.join(model_dir, 'model.h5')
        model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_path, compile = False)

        preprocessor_path = os.path.join(model_dir, 'bow.pkl')
        with open(preprocessor_path, 'rb') as f:
            bow_model = pickle.load(f)


        return cls(model, bow_model)
```

However i get

```
Prediction failed: Error when checking input: expected dense_input to have shape (2898,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

The problem seems to be due to the dimensions of my input data when trying to do the actual predictions, in line output = self._model.predict([vectors]). The model is expecting a vector of shape (2898, )

I am finding this quite odd... since when I print the shape and dimensions of the vector I get the following

```
This is the shape
(1, 2898)

This is the dim number
2

This is the vector 
[[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]
```

So the dimensions and the shape is fine and it should really be working....

Furthermore, I did a test to get the predictions of the model stored locally and it works fine. This is the test file:

```
import os
import pickle
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

class MyPredictor(object):

    def __init__(self, model, bow_model):
        self._model = model
        self._bow_model = bow_model

    def predict(self, instances, **kwargs):

        print("These are the instances ", instances)

        vector = self.embedding([instances])

        output = self._model.predict(vector)

        return output

    def embedding(self, statement):
        vector = self._bow_model.transform(statement).toarray()
        #vector = vector.to_list()
        return vector



model_path = 'model.h5'
model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_path, compile = False)

preprocessor_path = 'bow.pkl'
with open(preprocessor_path, 'rb') as f:
    bow_model = pickle.load(f)


instances = 'test'

predictor = MyPredictor(model, bow_model)

outputs = predictor.predict(instances)

print(outputs)
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved it!

It was as silly as adding a set of parenthesis to this line `output = self._model.predict([vectors])`

After that I got another error regarding the output of the prediction not being json serializable. This I solved simply by adding .tolist() to the return `return output.to_list()`

```
import os
import pickle
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import logging

class MyPredictor(object):

    def __init__(self, model, bow_model):
        self._model = model
        self._bow_model = bow_model

    def predict(self, instances, **kwargs):
      
        vectors = self.embedding([instances])

        vectors = vectors.tolist()

        output = self._model.predict([vectors])

        return output.to_list()

    def embedding(self, statement):
        vector = self._bow_model.transform(statement).toarray()
        #vector = vector.to_list()
        return vector


    @classmethod
    def from_path(cls, model_dir):

        model_path = os.path.join(model_dir, 'model.h5')
        model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_path, compile = False)

        preprocessor_path = os.path.join(model_dir, 'bow.pkl')
        with open(preprocessor_path, 'rb') as f:
            bow_model = pickle.load(f)


        return cls(model, bow_model)
```